# Including Server Connection File Error

Tags: php

I just started to include php files into my code so I don't have to copy and paste a bunch of stuff. I used to have my database connection in the same file but ever since I had put it in a different file it won't run a sql statement.

Original that works:

```
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $database = "db";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $conn = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database) or die(mysqli_error());
    $salt = 'salt';
    $test = rand();
    $pw_hash = md5($salt.$test);
    $isContractor = 0;
    if($_POST['userType'] == "Contractor") $isContractor = 1;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `UserHash` (`HashID`, `UserID`, `IsContractor`) VALUES ('".$pw_hash."', null, ".$isContractor.")";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(!$query){
        die("Error Found " . mysqli_error($conn));
    }else{
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">User Hash Created: ' . $pw_hash . '</div>';
    }
```

Separate files:

```
/Company/API/DatabaseConnection.php
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $database = "db";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $conn = new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database) or die(mysqli_error());

Hash.php
    include "../Company/API/DatabaseConnection.php";
    $salt = 'B7u3C0w';
    $test = rand();
    $pw_hash = md5($salt.$test);
    $isContractor = 0;
    if($_POST['userType'] == "Contractor") $isContractor = 1;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `UserHash` (`HashID`, `UserID`, `IsContractor`) VALUES ('".$pw_hash."', null, ".$isContractor.")";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(!$query){
        die("Error Found " . mysqli_error($conn));
    }else{
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">User Hash Created: ' . $pw_hash . '</div>';
    }
```

This will return the 'Error Found' that is from the !$query but no doesn't print out the error with it.

Comment: Print the generated query, there might be an error in it. also you are not doing the password hashing correctly. use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: Also, you are not testing if the connection is successful: `if (!$conn->connect_errno){ print error}`

Comment: @Ibu It works if the connection is in the same file. Also that if statement returned true.

Comment: use `$conn->query($sql)` to run your query.

Comment: @Ibu Still won't work.

Comment: I can't debug it without more context, but you might be getting errors. Turn on your errors. `ini_set('display_errors','On');` on the top, and check your error logs. Are you sure the path to the database file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**The file wasn't pulling the correct directory.**

I instead of using ../[filename] I just needed the /[filename]

The corrected code would be:

```
include "/Company/API/DatabaseConnection.php";
```

Comment: If you want to avoid using an absolute path, you should use `__DIR__` to ensure that the include path is correct. E.g., with Hash.php being where you originally specified, `__DIR__ . "/../Company/API/DatabaseConnection.php";`